# create array of array of datepairs that have gap of n days between them

Tags: javascript, date, split, date-format, dynamic-arrays

Consider 2 dates, format will be MM/DD/YYYY

1st date = today
2nd date = 45 days from today

Note: Here, the 1st date and 2nd date are variable.
i.e. 1st date that is today can be tomorrow or any other date. 2nd date can be 15 days, 24 days, 105 days i.e. this "n" can also vary.

Assuming the above 2 dates as startDate and stopDate. I want to create array of datePairs of a given gap between them.

For e.g. if startDate = 12/01/2022 & stopDate = 12/20/2022. I want to have datePairs having gap of 2 (n = 2) days between them. So, the output array should look like

```
[
    ['12/01/2022', '12/03/2022'],
    ['12/04/2022', '12/06/2022'],
    ['12/07/2022', '12/09/2022'],
    ['12/10/2022', '12/12/2022'],
    ['12/13/2022', '12/15/2022'],
    ['12/16/2022', '12/18/2022'],
    ['12/19/2022', '12/20/2022']
]
```

NOTE: Here, the last array does not have the gap of 2 dates because it's just 1 day away from the stopDate. In such case, the last pair can have less gap between them.

The only condition is the above array length should always be even.

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
};

function splitInto(array, size, inplace) {
    var output, i, group;
    if (inplace) {
        output = array;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            group = array.splice(i, size);
            output.splice(i, 0, group);
        }
    } else {
        output = [];
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += size) {
            output.push(array.slice(i, size + i));
        }
    }
    return output;
}

function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var currentDate = startDate;
    var i = 0;
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            const options = {
                year: 'numeric'
            };
            options.month = options.day = '2-digit';
            var formattedCSTDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options).format(currentDate);
            dateArray.push(formattedCSTDate);
            currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
        } else {
            const options = {
                year: 'numeric'
            };
            options.month = options.day = '2-digit';
            var formattedCSTDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options).format(currentDate);
            dateArray.push(formattedCSTDate);
            currentDate = currentDate.addDays(3);
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return dateArray;
};
var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(43));
var datePairLength = 2;
var rangeArray = splitInto(dateArray, datePairLength, false);
console.log(rangeArray);
```

Comment: Mutating prototype is considered bad practice. Reconsider `addDays` as a stand-alone function

Comment: Also, what’s the question? Do you want a code review? What exactly do you struggle with?

Comment: The above code does not work if I change the 45 days value. it creates array of odd length, which I don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. Just build each range as an array and avoid the *splitInto* function. You might use a date library (there are many to chose from) for adding days and formatting:

```js
function makeRanges(start = new Date(), end = new Date(), interval = 1) {
  let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', {
    year:'numeric',month:'short',day:'2-digit'
  });
  let s = new Date(start);
  let ranges = [];
  while (s < end) {
    let t = new Date(s);
    t.setDate(t.getDate() + interval);
    ranges.push([f.format(s), t < end? f.format(t) : f.format(end)]);
    s.setDate(s.getDate() + interval + 1)
  }
  return ranges;
}
console.log(
  makeRanges(new Date(2022,0,1), new Date(2022,1,1), 2)
);
```

Comment: If I want to give customStart as well, like to start calculating from tomorrow and not the given date, then?

Comment: Also, the format is MM/DD/YYYY to be used everywhere, both as input and output as well. I am receiving the dates as strings.

Comment: It calculates from the given date. If you want "tomorrow", then pass tomorrow as the start date. As for format, do it however you like. The OP doesn't specify MM/DD/YYYY, only `year: 'numeric'`, the rest of the formatting is left to the default language of the host, so for the vast majority of users (including me) it will be something else. If you want a specific order and format, use an appropriate BCP47 language code and options, e.g. `'en-us', {year:'numeric', month:'2-digit', day:'2-digit'}`.

Comment: if ((t - s / 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) === interval) {
 ranges.push([f.format(s), f.format(t)]);
}

I added this one line to handle the case where it misses the lastDate. Is this a correct suggest?

Comment: here -> https://playcode.io/1044549

Comment: You can just change `while (s < end)` to `while (s <= end)`.

Comment: You can try for larger duration like 45, 46, 47 days. Sometimes it misses the last date pair.

Comment: `s <= end` fixes that. Do you have a specific start date, end date and duration that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: oh yes. I was checking customizing with start and endDates with customStarts. my bad